Setting Up mosquitto-go-auth on Windows
I'm currently trying to set up mosquitto-go-auth on Windows 11, but I'm encountering some difficulties. The documentations mentioned in the Readme file of the Repo is completely based on linux and I could not find any documentations related to windows
on the web.
Could someone please provide a step-by-step guide or offer some advice on how to properly configure mosquitto-go-auth on Windows? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
Repo :
https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth.git
I tried with changing the location of the conf files in the docker file of the repo

Asking for tutorials is explicitly off topic for Stack Overflow. You need to include full details of what you've tried and how it didn't work in the question and we may be able to explain what you've done wrong, but we will not provide a tutorial.

The plug-in will not work on Windows, this is stated in the README.md in the building section. (I don't even think it is possible to build it on a none unix type OS).
If you want to use it on Windows you will need to run mosquitto + the plug-in in a Linux based Docker and supply a suitable mosquitto.conf file mounted into the container at /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
The docs provide details of where the plugin .so (/mosquitto/go-auth.so) file is in the pre-build container so you can include it in the configuration.

If you want to use it on Windows you will need to run mosquitto + the plug-in in a Linux based Docker and supply a suitable mosquitto.conf file mounted into the container at /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Can you help me in detail over this

No, try and if it doesn't work you can all a new question where you included details of what you tried and how it didn't work and something may help you fix it. That is how Stack Overflow works (p.s. that follow up question may be better suited to Server fault)
